# Interesting things in Garuda Purana chapter 15

Tags: puranas, karma, death, life, garuda-purana

While listening to today's Garuda Purana disclosure found a beautiful chapter 15 (An Account of the Coming to Birth of People who have done Good) .

> In this chapter The Purana in detail explains how and when the seed of
>   birth to be sowed to get good child and also explains the details on
>   how the embryo becomes child.
>
> This is the technology still medical science is not able to crack
>   which has been cracked by Indians thousands and thousands of years
>   ago.
>
> It even explains beyond first
>   anatomy of an pregnant women so called done by Leaonordo DA VINCI
>   similarly all other chapter are excellent and give details of life and
>   death.
>
> Beyond death some people say it is fantasy but one who sees
>   the chapter 15 with science will agree that this is fact known by
>   Hindus Thousands of years ago.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. The best way to do that in Stack Exchange is by posting a question and then answering it yourself. For example, ask a question about the scripture and then post the answer. However simply posting information in the form of a question is not allowed. Please edit it into a question or edit into a question and answer. ALl the best

Comment: As Sai said, as it stands you're not actually asking a question.  If you want to share knowledge with the community, then the procedure is to ask an actual question and the post an answer; I've done that myself, like my question and answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=Anukramani.  So I'm closing your question.

Comment: Science was unable to crack this but "Garuda Purana" was? Then I'm sure this should be useful for medicine and scientific reasons. Please notify the scientific community. This may be the discovery of the century.

Comment: Please provide the reference and details. If you make claims of surpassing modern medical science then evidence would be expected.

Answer (score -1):

Namaste

Do you not find it interesting that modern day science confirms that soul enters the embroyo in the month FIVE ? and that is why, it is welcomed by reciting slokas and hymns (i.e. the woman attaining that status participates in a ancient hindu sanskara called - Srimantum).

What modern science confirmed now, is written in Garuda purana in much more detailed and structured way.

Happy that you read that portion.

Comment: Please mention what your source is. Saying "science, confirms,science says, scientists say" without sources is misleading people who are easily tricked by such tactics.

Comment: By modern science do you mean **pseudo-science**

Answer (score -1):

Soul enters womb the moment seamen of men meets that of Women. This is very scientific and hope you will appreciate. 
What ever we eat end product is seamen. There are million of souls who are waiting to get a human form of body. It is said these souls millions in number through rains enter into grains and are residing in seamen of men which enter into women's womb. 
Based on once karma one is awarded this human form that is one out of million gets human form.
That's why it's said human form is most precious gift of nature and it is so rare.